# Why doesn't $f$ being Lebesgue integrable imply that the Hardy-Littlewood function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function on the reals. Define the Hardy-Littlewood function as $$f^{\ast}(x) = \sup\limits_{x \in B} \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B}|f(y)|dy,$$
where the supremum is taken over all balls $B$ containing $x.$ Let $$g(x) = \lim_{m(B) \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{m(B)}\int _{B} f(y)dy,$$ where $B$ contains $x$.

Now here is the question. Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative function. Is $f^{\ast} = g$ almost everywhere? If true then we must have the maximal function is integrable because the differentiation theorem implies $g(x) = f(x)$ almost everywhere. So if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, $g$ is integrable hence the maximal function is integrable.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of f*. Is B just an arbitrary ball around x? What does taking the sup over all points in the ball do?

Comment: That's the standard definition from real analysis. See the first paragraph of  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function

Comment: @PranavChinmay The sup is over all balls containing x.

Comment: The way you have defined $g,$ it is $0$ for any bounded function. And therefore $g=f$ almost everywhere does not hold.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho There was term missing. I fixed it. Thank you for that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $g=f$ almost everywhere. Now let $f(x)=x^2 \mathbf 1_{[-10,10]}\in L^1$. $f\ge 0$. Then, for all $x\in[-9,9]$, a lower bound for $f^*$ is given by $\frac12\int_{x-1}^{x+1} y^2 dy = x^2 + \frac13$. In particular, $f^*>f=g$, at least near $x=0$. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aomwevnqdq)'s a Desmos graph to verify. In fact $f^*(0)=100/3$, which is much larger than $f(0)=0$. You can similarly show that $f^*(x)>f(x)$ for all  $x\in(-10,10)$.

In addition, for any $x$ with $|x|>10$, there will always be some (possibly large) ball around $x$ that intersects $[-10,10]$. This implies $f^*(x)>0=f(x)$. In conclusion, $f^*>f$ almost everywhere.

One can make this last part for $|x|>10$ more precise (and this is close to what you might read in a book)： the ball of radius $|x|+10$ around $x$ completely contains $[-10,10]$. Consequently,
$$f^*(x)>\frac1{2|x|+20}\int_{-10}^{10} y^2 dy \ge \frac{C}{1+|x|}.$$ This proves that $f^*$ is not integrable at infinity.

Comment: If I just integrate x^2 from -1 to 2 and divide by the length of the interval which is 3 I get 1 which is not equal to f(0)=0. Thank you for clearing this up. But more importantly how do you know the integral you wrote is a lower bound for $f^{ast}$?

Comment: @user404735 Glad to help; the integral I wrote is the expression for $f^*$ without the sup, and for a particular $B$: its  $\frac1{ |B(x,1)|} \int _{B(x,1)} f(y) dy$. Its a lower bound as long as you have $f(y)=y^2$ for all $y\in B(x,1)$